# Integrate ASP.NET Forms Authentication with Third-Party Forums

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum

I know a lot of free/open-source `ASP.NET` Forum modules on the web. However, I don't know if any of them support integration of existing Forms Authentication on a website?

e.g. You already have an existing `ASP.NET` Website, with User Login and Registration, and you already have existing users registered.

All you want to do is add a Forum support to it and users should be able to use their existing log-in to post messages in the Forum.

Any ideas?

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: I did this with a coldfusion forums, and had to wire it up to check my database for authentication info.

Answer (score 0):

Try Nearforums, you can authenticate your users with asp.net membership or create a custom sso with your main site.
Disclaimer: I'm a Nearforums project team member.